What is the order of operations for cleaning up the attic, insulating, adding and attic fan and re-roofing?
I want to do this in the most cost effective way and to minimize re-work.
Some geo context… we live in Southern California where it doesn’t rain much generally, but the recent rains have shown the weak points of our roof.
The reason for the question is that we need to re-roof our house. And that brought up ideas for doing other projects around the same time.
We would also like to clean up the attic. There are tons of old wood pieces (large and small leftover from last time the roof was replaced), wood dust, etc that I would like to use a shop vac for.
I would also like to insulate and add an attic fan.
What should the order of operations be to reduce re-work and potential cost?

What type of roof are you talking about? What type of fan do you want to install, gable, through the roof?  Pricing is totally off topic here.

I would think redo of the roof first.  You do not want insulation to get wet.  Can also think of passive ventilation, soffit vents and ridge vent, saving the cost of running a fan.

Good idea regarding passive ventilation.

Whole-house fans can be useful in some environments, though it's very location dependent. Attic fans are almost never worthwhile, as they tend to draw in conditioned make-up air, among other problems.

1- reroof (remove large wood from attic now if possible). 2- clean up. 3- install fan. 4- insulate.

@JimmyFix-it. If we need to cut hole in roof for fan do we install fan first and then re-roof?

In that case yes, install fan while the roof is stripped IMO.
